# Building Mono from Source (not git) Fails with mcs: Command not found

Tags: build, mono

Building mono from downloaded source on an Android device.  Ran make get-monolite-latest and still get the following errors

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/bld/mono/mono-4.0.0/runtime'
if test -w /bld/mono/mono-4.0.0/mcs; then :; else chmod -R +w /bld/mono/mono-4.0.0/mcs; fi
cd /bld/mono/mono-4.0.0/mcs && make --no-print-directory -s NO_DIR_CHECK=1 PROFILES='binary_reference_assemblies net_4_5 xbuild_12 xbuild_14 monodroid  ' CC='gcc --sysroot=/usr/gcc-4.9.2/sysroot' all-profiles
make[6]: mcs: Command not found
make[6]: *** [build/deps/basic-profile-check.exe] Error 127
*** The compiler 'mcs' doesn't appear to be usable.
*** Trying the 'monolite' directory.
Illegal instruction
make[8]: *** [build/deps/basic-profile-check.exe] Error 132
*** The contents of your 'monolite' directory may be out-of-date
*** You may want to try 'make get-monolite-latest'
```

I've found what I think is the mcs executable in runtime/_tmpdir/bin, but copying it to where the build seems to be looking for it doesn't help.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

As the error message suggests: You may want to try the command 'make get-monolite-latest'

You need a certain mono version for building mono 4, I think it was >= 3.8 or so. The monolite should help out in this case.